# Lost session in firefox after return from paypal checkout

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I'm developing a commercial site using Asp.net C# which is integrated paypal express check out.

Everything works fine when my application runs in localhost with all browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox). But when I host my application on web server, session variables lost (all session variables become null) after return from paypal checkout page.

This problem happens only my application run with Firefox. Everything still works fine with IE and Chrome. Is there anyone got the same issues and know the solution to fix?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What technology are we talking about here? Could you add it to the tags?

Answer (score 1):

i think is normal, the normal flow is

1)client enter in site(SESSION START)

2)you set som session values/cookies

3)customer choose prodcuts,review is shopping cart,proceed to checkuout

4)customer left your page to go to paypal site(SESSION LOOSED)

5)complete purchase and come back to your site

Using paypal custom attributes to send all data that you need later so you can re-create the right information that you need when paypal redirect client to your site.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head here @makemoney2010. I saw this so many times when I was working at PayPal.. this is a very common problem. The best thing to do is to save that data in a database on your site, using the EC token as the reference value; or some user ID you create as a Primary/Indexed key in your database. If you don't save these values by the EC token, you will need to pass the unique value you created to PayPal, and read it on return. You could pass all user data to paypal, but I do not recommend it, and usually this is not possible nor desired. PayPal is not your data-store.

Comment: Sure SgtPooki, when i wrote send all data that you need i intend exactly these : Store data in sql or mysql server and passw just a simple id or encrypted value like a string which contains few data to match the same into database and recreate same session when paypal response come back.And also there's the issue about IPN which need to be structered as well if someone want to authomize processing procs. lol